# Why do I still see differences in files after an hg pull and/or update?

Tags: mercurial

I've been using Mercurial for a couple weeks without issues, but I've run into a question this morning.  I've tried running both "hg pull" and "hg update" to get all file changes from the repository as follows.  However, when I run "hg diff" afterwards, I still see file changes.

```
> hg pull
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 7 changesets with 8 changes to 6 files

> hg update
6 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

> hg diff
(a file change is listed)
```

How do I get to the point where "hg diff" will yield zero changes?

PS - hg status yields one change:

```
M aPath\bPath\cPath\MyForm.Designer.cs
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `hg status`?  Perhaps you have a file that has been added, but not yet committed to your local repo?

Comment: I've edited post.  Hg status lists every file in the project w/ a ? in the Stat column, but one file w/ an M in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you are seeing simply mean that your `MyForm.Designer.cs` file has changes that you did not commit (i.e. local modifications).  You can see how you changed the file using `hg diff`.

You have two options to deal with the local modifications:

1. Commit and push the local modifications
2. Discard the local change (`hg update --clean`)

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't updated that file intentionally.  I guess when I had it opened, I must have made some change accidentally.  'Good to know for future!

Answer (score 1):

`hg pull` updates only repo

```
This finds all changes from the repository at the specified path or URL
and adds them to a local repository (the current one unless -R is
specified). By default, this does not update the copy of the project in
the working directory.
```

you have to `hg up` in order to update Working Copy. And I can't see any correlation between diff and results of pull - undo local changes you can in more easy and fast and correct way

Comment: I've also tried "hg update", but I still see changes when I run "hg diff" (I've edited my question).

Comment: @WEFX - diff what with what? And after what?

Comment: Please see revision.  Thanks for the help.